# More than one row return in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have a Postgresql code that return more one value in subquery following below.
that i want to return year, month, region, name, total incoming (this has conditional where), and total sales (this has conditional where which has different conditional with total incoming). Sure my logic is wrong. but anybody help me to solve this case?

```
select 
    distinct 
        x.year_s_date Tahun, 
        x.month_s_date Bulan, 
        y.regionalname Region, 
        y.namarm nama_rm,
        (select 
            distinct sum(s_totalfinancing) incoming
            from staging.main_eform_kpm_final a
            inner join (
                select * 
                from landing.confins_dwh_rmkmb 
                where enddate > '2020-01-01'
            ) b on a.branch_code = b.branchid
           where a.db_source is not null
           group by a.year_s_date, a.month_s_date, b.regionalname, b.namarm
        ),
        (
            select distinct sum(s_totalfinancing) sales
            from staging.main_eform_kpm_final a
            inner join (
                select * 
                from landing.confins_dwh_rmkmb 
                where enddate > '2020-01-01'
            ) b on a.branch_code = b.branchid
            where a.db_source is not null and a.db_source_2 is not null and lineage ='1'
            group by a.year_s_date, a.month_s_date, b.regionalname, b.namarm
        )
    from staging.main_eform_kpm_final x
    inner join (
        select * 
        from landing.confins_dwh_rmkmb 
        where enddate > '2020-01-01'
    ) y on x.branch_code = y.branchid
```

Comment: Use  `limit 1` in your subquery

Comment: it doesnt help because the 1st subquery and 2nd subquery is only different in where conditional, if use limit 1 that return only one value.i checked for every subquery it return differenct count

Comment: Hi @HandriMauludinMaulana it's better if you provide table structure with sample data and expected output. Multiple corelated subquery can degrade performance.